# Java switch : variable declaration and scope

Tags: java, scope, initialization, switch-statement, variable-declaration

How does the Java compiler handle the following switch block ?
What is the scope of the 'b' variable ?

Note that the 'b' variable is declared only in the first branch of the switch statement. Attempting to declare it in the second branch as well results in a "duplicate local variable" compilation error.

```
    int a = 3;
    switch( a ) {
    case 0:
        int b = 1;
        System.out.println("case 0: b = " + b);
        break;
    case 1:
        // the following line does not compile: b may not have been initialized
        // System.out.println("case 1 before: b = " + b);
        b = 2;
        System.out.println("case 1 after: b = " + b);
        break;
    default:
        b = 7;
        System.out.println("default: b = " + b);
    }
```

Note: the above code compiles with a java 1.6 compiler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The scope is, just as usual, delimited by `{` and `}`.

Comment: Message to OP, you can put braces around each case and then it would work. As in `case 1: { doHere(); break; }`

Answer (score 12):

The scope of `b` is the block. You have only one block which includes all `case`s. That's why you get a compile error when you redeclare `b` in your second `case`.

You could wrap each `case` in an own block like

```
case 0:
   {
     int b = 1;
     ...
   }
case 1:
   {
     int b = 2;
     ...
   }
```

but I think FindBugs or CheckStyle would complain about that.

Comment: The compile error is not from _redeclaring_ `b` but from accessing it before it is initialized. `b` is perfectly valid in case 0, 1, and default because as you mention it is in scope. The issue with his commented line not compiling is that b is not initialized before it is accessed.

Comment: I should have read the question more careful. I thought he was doing `int b = 2` in the commented out line ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The scope of `b` is the switch block - between the declaration and the delimiter `}` -

```
int a = 3;

switch( a ) {
     case 0:
          int b = 1; //scope starts
          System.out.println("case 0: b = " + b);
          break;
     case 1:
          // the following line does not compile: b may not have been initialized
          // System.out.println("case 1 before: b = " + b);
          b = 2;
          System.out.println("case 1 after: b = " + b);
          break;
     default:
          b = 7;
          System.out.println("default: b = " + b);
}//scope ends
```

However, you need to know that if you declare the `int b` inside the `case 1:`, you will NOT have access to the variable `b` inside the `case 0:`

To answer the question you ask in the java comments you can check this simpler example:

```
int b;
if(true){
    b++; //The local variable b hast not been initialized
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the scope using {} around your case.

```
int a = 3;
switch( a ) {
case 0: {
    int b = 1;
    System.out.println("case 0: b = " + b);
    break;
}
case 1: {
    // the following line does not compile: b may not have been initialized
    // System.out.println("case 1 before: b = " + b);
    int b = 2;
    System.out.println("case 1 after: b = " + b);
    break;
}
default: {
    int b = 7;
    System.out.println("default: b = " + b);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code if a is not equal to 0 b will never be initialized. you should define b before the switch statement.

Comment: The problem is at compile time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your `case` blocks do not have any local scope. It's not a series of `if`...`else if`...`else` blocks, java implements it as a series of `GOTO`s.

Answer (score 0):

The Scope of variables defined in a `switch()` statement would be the same as in a normal block wich is surround by `{` and `}`.

Therefore every variable defined in a `switch()` statement is visible for the whole block, once it is defined.