# Why isn't the scope of a switch statement in Java limited?

Tags: java, switch-statement, scope, language-design

Why, in Java, is a variable's scope confined to a switch block as opposed to a case block. For example,

```
// Scope limited to a switch block
switch (number) {
case 1:
    String result = "...";
    break;
case 2:
    result = "...";
    break;
```

In the above example, result needs only to be declared once. If you declare it twice then you receive a `Duplicate local variable` message.

My question is: how does the program know you've declared `result` if `number = 2`?
(It won't fall into `case 1` and won't declare the variable... or will it?)

EDIT:

I might be confusing everyone. I understand how I can limit the scope of a variable but my question is: *how does Java know that result has been declared if it doesn't fall into the case*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java switch : variable declaration and scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932997/java-switch-variable-declaration-and-scope)

Comment: This is a duplicate, thanks - I'll delete. EDIT: Can't delete - will flag.

Comment: Edited my answer. Also helped you by voting to close :-)

Comment: @sdasdadas You don't have to delete - it's fine for the community just to close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Java uses **lexical scoping** (also called static scoping), so the scope of the variables are determined during compile time, and have nothing to do with the actual evaluation.

Java is block scoped, so it's scope will respect the `{}` in the example above.

See [JLS 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in
>   the local variable declaration statement.

Comment: What you call static scoping is more commonly called lexical scoping.

Answer (score 6):

You can limit the scope to case blocks by adding curly brackets like this:

```
// Scope limited to a switch block
switch (number) {
case 1:{
    String result = "...";
    break;
}
case 2:{
    String result = "...";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the grandfather language Fortran, there is a computed GOTO statement

```
        GOTO expr
        ...
    1   ...
        ...
    2   ...
        ...
```

based on the value of `expr`, the code jumps to 1, 2 etc.

C's (and Java's) `switch` statement is basically a computed GOTO in disguise. We have a continuous piece of code with some labels, and we jump to one of the label. If there's no `break` we'll execute the rest of the block.

This rather low level control mechanism is contrary to the intuitions of today's programmers; we would think that the switch statement selects one clause and executes that clause, much like an `if-elseif-elseif-...-else`  statement.

Java inherited C's switch semantics since they didn't want to deviate from C too much. Newer languages are unlikely to continue the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses block scoping, select cases aren't blocks (they are more like labels).  This would work though:

```
switch (key) {
case 1: {
    String result = "1";
    return result ;
  }
case 2: {
    String result = "2";
    return result ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Missed it by 9 seconds!?  Go Ahead Ziyao, you earned it :)

Comment: I appreciate both of your answers but my main question is: how, then, is the variable declared?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean how? In order to understand the answer you need to learn how compilers work.
Think of the switch as a large block with multiple "goto" statements at the end of each switch statement.

I'm not sure how java unroll switch statements but one easy and simple way to do it is this (pseudo byte-code):

```
    if (number == 1) goto label1;
    if (number == 2) goto label2;
    goto labelEnd;
label1:
    String result = "...";
    goto labelEnd;
label2:
    result = "...";
    goto labelEnd;
labelEnd:
    <some code>
```

Comment: what the OP probably meant was: if number is equal to 2, and it goes to label 2: it encounters the variable result. But result was declared only after label1(which was not executed) as it jumped directly to label2(in this example atleast)

Answer (score 0):

The reason a variable scope is confined to a  switch block as opposed to a case block is java allows for fall through from one case block to the next i.e.

```
switch (number) {
case 1:
     .... some code ...
case 2:
     .... some more code ...
```

in this case case if number is 1, both case 1 & case 2 are executed. The break acts like a goto end of select, it does not ever end scope. The variable scope has to be at **select level**.

As others have stated, use a block to restrict scope i.e.

```
switch (number) {
case 1:{
    String result = "...";
    break;
}
case 2:{
    String result = "...";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there isn't a 'case block'.

Everything inside the switch statement is in the same block. You can't declare the same variable twice in the same block.

If you want a 'case block' you have to write the `{` and `}` yourself.